# .htaccess insert a string inside the URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have no experience whatsoever with .htaccess and I've been reading for awhile now but to no success. My site is using wordpress and I need to edit the .htaccess file to insert a string inside my url just like this.

`mysite.com/?a=c&b=2` to this `mysite.com/mobile?a=c&b=2`

So if I enter the first URL it'll proceed to the next one. Also, since my site is using wordpress, I have no idea where to insert the codes.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<FilesMatch "wp-login.php">
AuthName "WordPress Admin"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /usr/www/users/ineedjkfup/./wp-admin/.htpasswd
require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

help me Gurus. Please. :D :D